# I tried to access the name property of a radio input in the DOM, but apparently all the name fields have a value of false?

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="tab">Question 1 of 12
      <p><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</p>
</div>
```

I have a couple of elements with the same html format as above, and i'm trying to perform some operation in which i'll need the value of the name property,

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab")
var y = x[0].getElementsByTagName("input")
```

in this case, `y[0].name` should evaluate to "gender", instead it evaluates to false as does all other input name properties. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the issue is, you are facing issue retrieving value from the input?

Answer (score -1):

This fragment seems to be ok.
y[0].name returns 'gender' as expected.

It's probably something else in your code.